# "instance" part is not deleted by buildout when switching to 2 Plone instances using buildout section extension

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

We're switching from one to two Zope instances for our productoin Plone deployment. I have the following buildout structure defined:

buildout.cfg

```
[buildout]
extends = app.cfg
... some environment specific stuff
```

app.cfg

```
[buildout]
extends = base.cfg

parts =
    zope2
    productdistros
    instance1
    instance2
    zopepy
    supervisor

[instance1]
<= instance
http-address = 18081

[instance2]
<= instance
http-address = 18082
```

base.cg

```
[buildout]
parts =
    zope2
    productdistros
    instance
    zopepy

... bulk of buildout configuration suitable for both server and development
```

Testing this I'd expect this buildout configuration to result in the existing instance part to be deleted and replaced with instance1 and instance2.  However the instance part is not deleted - it can still be found in bin and parts directory.

```
[zopetest@dev home]$ bin/buildout
Updating zope2.
Updating fake eggs
Updating productdistros.
Updating instance1.
Updating instance2.
Updating instance.
Updating zopepy.
Updating supervisor.
```

I have a very similar set-up on a different zope instance that was configured this way from the start and it has no "instance" part.

We're running zc.buildout 1.4.4 with Python 2.4.6 building Plone 3.3.6.

I've tried the following with no change:
* upgrading to buildout 1.5.2
* removing the parts assignment from base.cfg

Comment: I think this is an issue with buildout (a bug?) because instance is defined as dependendency. Try delete all dotted files (.installed.cfg or something) and see if it helps buildout to forget instance.

Comment: No luck.  I also tried deleting the bin and parts directories and running `python bootstrap.py` and that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact due to the zc.buildout [automatic part selection](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.7.1#automatic-part-selection-and-ordering) feature

> When a section with a recipe is referred to, either through variable substitution or by an initializing recipe, the section is treated as a part and added to the part list before the referencing part

I had the following section

```
[zopepy]
# For more information on this step and configuration options see:
# http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.egg
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${instance:eggs}
```

As it referenced the “instance” section “instance” was included in the list of parts.

To fix I changed it to copy-paste the eggs value of instance

```
eggs =
    Plone
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

and then ran bin/buildout

Answer (score 1):

This is a "feature" of [plone.recipe.zope2instance](https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance). Traditionally the recipe has avoided removal of the instances and scripts it creates for running plone (for whatever reason: either poor design or deliberate decision, I am not sure).

For whatever it is worth, as of version 4.2.0 there is [support for generating non-plone scripts](https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/blob/master/README.txt#L349) (similar to zc.recipe.egg) and those scripts are managed properly. See:

- [https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/blob/master/src/plone/recipe/zope2instance/**init**.py#L119](https://github.com/plone/plone.recipe.zope2instance/blob/master/src/plone/recipe/zope2instance/__init__.py#L119)

for all the gory details. (I believe the "feature" is that the install method does not return a tuple, unless you are using scripts in which case a tuple containing the scripts is returned.)

Comment: Thanks Alex.  That makes sense but is there a way I can remove it manually then?

Comment: You can just rm -rf parts/instance, IIUC what you are asking.

Comment: I already tried deleting the bin and parts directories before running `python bootstrap.py` but that didn't work